# ¿Como cambiar el tipo de dato desde la consulta?

Tags: sql, groovy

Tengo esta consulta en un programa hecho en `groovy`:

```
query = """SELECT DISTINCT FOLIO, ID_CALLIDUS
FROM TRANS_WF_SEC WHERE FOLIO IS NOT NULL AND(ID_PADRE = '${id_master}' OR ID_HIJO = '${id_master}') AND FECHA_CIERRE BETWEEN '${fecha2}' AND '${fecha}'
"""
```

trayendo los datos desde una base pero el `between` no me funciona ya que el tipo de dato que viene de la base es `string` y el que uso para comparar es `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FOLIO, ID_CALLIDUS 
FROM TRANS_WF_SEC 
WHERE FOLIO IS NOT NULL 
    AND(ID_PADRE = '${id_master}' OR ID_HIJO = '${id_master}') 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),FECHA_CIERRE,120) BETWEEN '${fecha2}' AND '${fecha}
```

O también:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FOLIO, ID_CALLIDUS  FROM TRANS_WF_SEC  WHERE FOLIO IS NOT NULL 
    AND(ID_PADRE = '${id_master}' OR ID_HIJO = '${id_master}') 
    AND CAST(FECHA_CIERRE AS CHAR(10)) BETWEEN '${fecha2}' AND '${fecha}
```